# href attribute of <a> is automatically trimmed in cakePHP post method

Tags: html, forms, post, tinymce, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to submit a form which consists of text fields and tiny mce editor. The tiny mce editor contains *raw html elements* like this

```
<a href="http://testserver/my-development-app/web/users/profile/4567/3323" target="_blank">View Profile</a>
```

After submitting the form via **POST** method using *cakePHP*, the *href* attribute of *anchor* tag value is automatically trimmed like this

```
<a href="../profile/4567/3323" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View Profile</a>
```

What is wrong here? Why the *href* attribute url is trimmed after submitting the form ?

Comment: This is almost certainly a result of [TinyMCE's URL handling](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/), nothing to do with Cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the **tiny mce editor** to handle the urls. Make sure in the javascript initialization you are using, that you have these lines in it:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : true,
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set `relative_urls` to `false`. By default TinyMCE will assume that all links are relative to where the editor is.